# Call to undefined member function adminInitiateAuth() with cognito in AWS

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

```
$this->client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient([
  'version' => '2016-04-18',
  'region' => 'us-east-1',
]);
$result = $this->client->adminInitiateAuth([
    'AuthFlow' => 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
    'ClientId' => $this->client_id,
    'UserPoolId' => $this->userpool_id,
    'AuthParameters' => [
        'USERNAME' => 'xxxx',
        'PASSWORD' => 'xxxxxx',
    ],
]);
```

I am using the same code by creating a function given below:

```
public function authenticate(string $username, string $password) : string
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->client->adminInitiateAuth([
                'AuthFlow' => 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
                'ClientId' => $this->client_id,
                'UserPoolId' => $this->userpool_id,
                'AuthParameters' => [
                    'USERNAME' => $username,
                    'PASSWORD' => $password,
                ],
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

        $this->setAuthenticationCookie($result->get('AuthenticationResult')['AccessToken']);

        return '';
    }
```

I created a REST API call and called this function. I am getting an error call to undefined member **adminInitiateAuth()**. I have declared the credentials in .env file(ClientID, Region, userpoolID).

I have initialized $this->client as below:

```
public function initialize() : void
    {
        $this->client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient([
          'version' => '2016-04-18',
          'region' => $this->region,
        ]);

        try {
            $this->user = $this->client->getUser([
                'AccessToken' => $this->getAuthenticationCookie()
            ]);
        } catch(\Exception  $e) {
            // an exception indicates the accesstoken is incorrect - $this->user will still be null
        }
    }
```

Please find the full class code:

```
<?php
namespace AWSCognitoApp;

use Aws\CognitoIdentityProvider\CognitoIdentityProviderClient;

class AWSCognitoWrapper
{
    private const COOKIE_NAME = 'aws-cognito-app-access-token';

    private $region;
    private $client_id;
    private $userpool_id;

    private $client;

    private $user = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if(!getenv('REGION') || !getenv('CLIENT_ID') || !getenv('USERPOOL_ID')) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Please provide the region, client_id and userpool_id variables in the .env file");
        }

        $this->region = getenv('REGION');
        $this->client_id = getenv('CLIENT_ID');
        $this->userpool_id = getenv('USERPOOL_ID');
        $this->client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient([
            'version' => '2016-04-18',
            'region' => $this->region,
          ]);
    }

    /*public function initialize() : void
    {
        $this->client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient([
          'version' => '2016-04-18',
          'region' => $this->region,
        ]);

        try {
            $this->user = $this->client->getUser([
                'AccessToken' => $this->getAuthenticationCookie()
            ]);
        } catch(\Exception  $e) {
            // an exception indicates the accesstoken is incorrect - $this->user will still be null
        }
    }*/

    public function authenticate(string $username, string $password) : string
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->client->adminInitiateAuth([
                'AuthFlow' => 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
                'ClientId' => $this->client_id,
                'UserPoolId' => $this->userpool_id,
                'AuthParameters' => [
                    'USERNAME' => $username,
                    'PASSWORD' => $password,
                ],
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

        $this->setAuthenticationCookie($result->get('AuthenticationResult')['AccessToken']);

        return '';
    }

    public function signup(string $username, string $email, string $password) : string
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->client->signUp([
                'ClientId' => $this->client_id,
                'Username' => $username,
                'Password' => $password,
                'UserAttributes' => [
                    [
                        'Name' => 'name',
                        'Value' => $username
                    ],
                    [
                        'Name' => 'email',
                        'Value' => $email
                    ]
                ],
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

        return '';
    }

    public function confirmSignup(string $username, string $code) : string
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->client->confirmSignUp([
                'ClientId' => $this->client_id,
                'Username' => $username,
                'ConfirmationCode' => $code,
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

        return '';
    }

    public function sendPasswordResetMail(string $username) : string
    {
        try {
            $this->client->forgotPassword([
                'ClientId' => $this->client_id,
                'Username' => $username
            ]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

        return '';
    }

    public function resetPassword(string $code, string $password, string $username) : string
    {
        try {
            $this->client->confirmForgotPassword([
                'ClientId' => $this->client_id,
                'ConfirmationCode' => $code,
                'Password' => $password,
                'Username' => $username
            ]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

        return '';
    }

    public function isAuthenticated() : bool
    {
        return null !== $this->user;
    }

    public function getPoolMetadata() : array
    {
        $result = $this->client->describeUserPool([
            'UserPoolId' => $this->userpool_id,
        ]);

        return $result->get('UserPool');
    }

    public function getPoolUsers() : array
    {
        $result = $this->client->listUsers([
            'UserPoolId' => $this->userpool_id,
        ]);

        return $result->get('Users');
    }

    public function getUser() : ?\Aws\Result
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        if(isset($_COOKIE[self::COOKIE_NAME])) {
            unset($_COOKIE[self::COOKIE_NAME]);
            setcookie(self::COOKIE_NAME, '', time() - 3600);
        }
    }

    private function setAuthenticationCookie(string $accessToken) : void
    {
        /*
         * Please note that plain-text storage of the access token is insecure and
         * not recommended by AWS. This is only done to keep this example
         * application as easy as possible. Read the AWS docs for more info:
         * http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html
        */
        setcookie(self::COOKIE_NAME, $accessToken, time() + 3600);
    }

    private function getAuthenticationCookie() : string
    {
        return $_COOKIE[self::COOKIE_NAME] ?? '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you initiated $this->client before you call "authenticate" ?

Comment: Yes @AgeValed. 

 public function initialize() : void
    {
        $this->client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient([
          'version' => '2016-04-18',
          'region' => $this->region,
        ]);

        try {
            $this->user = $this->client->getUser([
                'AccessToken' => $this->getAuthenticationCookie()
            ]);
        } catch(\Exception  $e) {
            // an exception indicates the accesstoken is incorrect - $this->user will still be null
        }
    }

Comment: so you are doing something like the following? 

`$test = new className();
$test->initialize(); //or this can called from the __constructor
$test->authenticate('user','pass');
`

Comment: @imlokeshs try `public function __constuct()` instead of `public function initialize()`

Comment: I have checked under __construct() too. But the same error occurs. @AlexHarris

Comment: No @AgeValed under authenticate function there is a client function named **adminInitiateAuth()**. This function is undefined

Comment: @imlokeshs what package are you using?

Comment: @imlokeshs you have some issue with the initialization of the variable client, can you add the full class, not only the `public function authenticate` **EDIT** also add the code where you call the function authenticate.

Comment: Laravel package **aws/aws-sdk-php** @AlexHarris

Comment: I have added full class code. @AgeValed

Comment: if you do on a controller 

`$classAWSCognitoWrapper = new AWSCognitoWrapper();

$classAWSCognitoWrapper->$classAWSCognitoWrapper('user','pass');'

you get the error? with that must work fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are using the package incorrectly.

Try the following:

```
    $this->client = CognitoIdentityProviderClient::factory([
        'region' => $region,
        'version' => $version
    ]);

    $result = $this->client->adminInitiateAuth([
        'UserPoolId'     => $this->poolId,
        'ClientId'       => $this->clientId,
        'AuthFlow'       => 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH', // this matches the 'server-based sign-in' checkbox setting from earlier
        'AuthParameters' => [
            'USERNAME' => $username,
            'PASSWORD' => $password
        ]
    ]);
```

I found a [simple guide](https://tech.mybuilder.com/managing-authentication-in-your-symfony-project-with-aws-cognito/) that I am referencing that you might want to look at.